# Parse error when trying to access constant of subobject,

Tags: php

I've discovered a very strange behavior of PHP. This code:

```
   class Foo
{
    const CONSTANT = 'SomeValue';
}

class Bar
{
    public $tmp;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->tmp = new Foo;
    }
}

$object = new Bar;
echo $object->tmp::CONSTANT;
```

Gives a parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ',' or ';' in E:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.local\test.php on line 18

What a hell is that? Why it works only if I introduce an intermediate variable:

```
$interm = $object->tmp;
echo $interm::CONSTANT
```

I really don't need any additional variables.

PHP 5.6.3

Comment: `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` is the name of the `::` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the class constant via the class name, not the object.

e.g. `echo Foo::CONSTANT;`

Comment: Ok, but there may be another class object in that property.